# Android Lint does not see unused png drawables

Tags: android, lint

I have many unused (hundreds) png drawables in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi... folders. Lint check gives me only unused **layouts, strings, animations** and **xml drawables**, but not **png** drawables. 
Another tool [android-unused-resources](https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/) gives me "0 resources found". I've checked, that drawables really unused (I have searched on a whole project for drawable name, tried to delete drawable and it was OK). Why so that and how to make lint detect them as "unused"?

Comment: Is there a lint.xml file in your project's folder? If yes, can you post its contents?

Comment: I have the same problem. +1 for putting a bounty on it. @shoerat I'm using AndroidStudio and my lint.xml is empty, just `<?xml version...` and `<lint></lint>`

Comment: @Budius, check if "Unused resources" is checked at Android Studio -> File: Settings -> Inspections -> Android Lint

Comment: @shoerat I've created a Inspection Profile just for this. So my lint is only checking that as I took the day to just clear the project.

Comment: yes I have a lint.xml file and it have many "issue", one of them:

    <issue id="UnusedResources" severity="ignore" />

Comment: I rememer it can pick up unused png in the past. I have started a session in mail group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/NiZD9n4qtwI)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> `I have a lint.xml file and it have many "issue", one of them: <issue id="UnusedResources" severity="ignore" />`

It seems that your Lint is configured to ignore unused resources.

To change that, go in `Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking` and either search for the *UnusedResources* issues, or look under the *Performance* tab and change the severity of this issue to at least Information or Warning, or even something more severe, as you wish.

[image]

Comment: I use Intellij Idea. I've tried to change severity to "error" in lint.xml file. Also I've tried to change in Intellij Idea Analyze  settings for "unused resources" to error. And still nothing. I'm getting warnings about another resources, but not for png drawables.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, not a fix for your issue. I noticed that lint stopped working in my environment (Eclipse) and started using the command line version of the tool which can be found in your /tools/

I run the command in the terminal with:

```
./lint ~/workspace/<your-project-folder>
```

Make sure the lint file is setup to be executed. The output will be a list of warnings from lint. I suggest copying that into a text editor in order to quickly search for keywords. All of the warnings related to your issue should be under [UnusedResources] and grouped together.

Comment: I will try it, but I'm getting warnings for another unused resources: xml drawables, layouts, but not for the png drawables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lint.xml file in your project directory, this overrides settings made in Android Studio. This happened to me somehow maybe because I imported the project from Eclipse a long time ago.

Remove the lint.xml file and Lint will use the settings made inside Android Studio using Analyze/Inspect Code.